# SqlServer.Dmf.dll required in Global Assembly Cache upon wpf app installation

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2012, clickonce

I have an wpf app that creates a database to file. Just uses (LocalDB)/v11.0 in the connection string not .SQLExpress. If i go in project properties and go to publish tab and click on Application files, i tell it to Exclude SQlServer.Dmf.dll and yet when I publish it still ask for that dll. Why is this? I am not using this dll anywhere in my app nor do I think it should be required that i add it to my references. If I install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 then on the machine I'm trying to install on then it will work. But for what Im doing I shouldn't need to install sql server 2012. Im only ever using a local db .mdf(along with log) in file. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files listed in `Project Properties > Publish > Application Files` is automatically compiled by Visual Studio. Your application must require these DLLs. If they are not already registered on the machine then setting them to `excluded` will generate the error you describe.

You should either set the assemblies to `Included` or if this adds unacceptable size overhead to your distribution then you can go to `Project Properties > Publish > Prerequisites` and add  `SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB`

Comment: I have excluded all the libs beginning with "Microsoft.sqlServer." but it still gives me this error... I have also set as prerequisite sql server 2012 express, but it ask always for the version 10 (related to sql server 2008). If I install instead sql server 2008, it is ok. But why, if I install sql server 2012, it asks me for the lib of sql server 2008?